# What would be the opposite phrase for "Drawee Bank"?

Tags: antonyms

Drawee bank is the bank, who will pay the cheque/draft. Then what would we call the bank in which the cheque/draft will be deposited?

I did some search over the internet and found this [link](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Who_is_the_payee_bank?#slide=2). Is it correct to call it "Payee Bank" or some other phrase is more suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bank receiving the money (the payee gets whatever from the payer). payee bank will do the job just fine.